# What were the Five Tenets?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've seen the Five Tenets posted on the walls of the Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary, but the print is faded, smudged, and very small.  Has anyone been able to make out what they used to be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the book "The Five Tenets" in Oblivion:

Tenet 1: Never dishonor the Night Mother. To do so is to invoke the Wrath of Sithis.

Tenet 2: Never betray the Dark Brotherhood or its secrets. To do so is to invoke the Wrath of Sithis.

Tenet 3: Never disobey or refuse to carry out an order from a Dark Brotherhood superior. To do so is to invoke the Wrath of Sithis.

Tenet 4: Never steal the possessions of a Dark Brother or Dark Sister. To do so is to invoke the Wrath of Sithis.

Tenet 5: Never kill a Dark Brother or Dark Sister. To do so is to invoke the Wrath of Sithis.

Comment: These were secret...You have invoked the Wrath of Sithis...

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Well, I guess I did tell you, so now I have to kill you. Sithis demands it.

Comment: For what it's worth, it was impossible to break any of the first three tenets in game.

Comment: Him and his Sharks spent a few hours after locking themselves in the Night Mothers coffin trying to break the 1st one :P

Comment: @RavenDreamer You could break the third tenet.  Nothing will happen though.  Of course, you'll have a quest or two left open that will never progress either.

Comment: @Iszi - "Nothing will happen though" - then you haven't broken it. :P I remember a very angry "Wrath of Sithis" fight when the others get broken.